# Git rebase a local branch that doesn't have a remote

Tags: git, git-rebase

I created a local branch (`git checkout -b`) in which I did some dirty commits ("WIP" and such). I never pushed to the remote. I now want to rename/squash some the commits before pushing :

```
$ git rebase -i
There is no tracking information for the current branch.
Please specify which branch you want to rebase against.
See git-rebase(1) for details

    git rebase <branch>

If you wish to set tracking information for this branch you can do so with:

    git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/<branch> feature/position-preview
```

I then do as suggested :

```
$ git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/feature/my-feature feature/my-feature
error: the requested upstream branch 'origin/position-preview' does not exist
hint:
hint: If you are planning on basing your work on an upstream
hint: branch that already exists at the remote, you may need to
hint: run "git fetch" to retrieve it.
hint:
hint: If you are planning to push out a new local branch that
hint: will track its remote counterpart, you may want to use
hint: "git push -u" to set the upstream config as you push.
```

The thing is, I don't want to `push -u` as it is, because it would result in a bad history.

How do I rebase my new local branch ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Git's documentation is the subject of [much](http://git-man-page-generator.lokaltog.net/) [derision](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=7565885) ... with good reason:

> git rebase [-i | --interactive] [options] [--exec <cmd>] [--onto <newbase>] [<upstream> [<branch>]]

The argument here is labeled `upstream`, and the helpful (?) output from the command refers to `git branch --set-upstream-to` and `origin/<branch>`, which implies that your local branch has to have a remote branch like `origin/my-feature` for this to work.  But that's not the case at all.

What `git rebase` does is to *copy* a series of commits, with each copy happening as if you'd run `git cherry-pick` on one particular commit.  By copying *every* commit in some linear chain of commits within the commit-graph, you get the effect of copying a branch-of-development.<sup>1</sup>  This makes more sense expressed in graph form, I think.  For instance, suppose you have this sequence:

```
... <- o <- A <- B    <-- master
         \
           C <- D <- E   <-- my-feature
```

where each letter stands for some particular commit—one of those big ugly 40-character SHA-1 numbers—and the commit history for `my-feature` joins up with the commit-history for `master` at commit `o`.  This is the kind of graph you'd get if you made a new branch `my-feature` while on `master`, then went back to branch `master`, made two commits, and went to `my-feature` and made three commits (the actual order in which you make each commit doesn't matter: I just need you to have made two on `master`, and I drew them up *now* as first-of-those `A` and second-one `B`, and three on `my-feature`).

Now, as it happens with development, you might decide it would make more sense to have `C`-through-`E` based on the current tip of `master`, i.e., to have `C`'s parent commit be `B`.

A very manual method to achieve this is:

```
$ git checkout master
$ git checkout -b new-my-feature
$ git cherry-pick <id of commit C>
$ git cherry-pick <id of commit D>
$ git cherry-pick <id of commit E>
```

This makes a new branch, `new-my-feature`, and copies three commits,<sup>2</sup> with this result:

```
                C' - D' - E'   <-- new-my-feature
              /
... o - A - B   <-- master
      \
        C - D - E    <-- my-feature
```

The way git constructs new commit `C'` is to compare the tree—the associated source snapshot—for `C` to that for its parent commit `o`, apply that same change to the tree for `B`, and make a new commit that re-uses the commit message for `C`.  In other words, commit `C'` is a "copy" of `C`.  The same goes for `D'` from `D`, and for `E'` from `E`.

In any case, if you take this third picture and then delete the `my-feature` branch label and rename `new-my-feature` to `my-feature`, what you get is:

```
                C' - D' - E'   <-- my-feature
              /
... o - A - B   <-- master
```

The original three commits on the old `my-feature` are "lost" (they're kept for 30 days through "reflog" entries, but those are normally invisible so as to avoid cluttering up your view).

What `git rebase` does is automate this process: it finds a sequence of commits to copy, copies the sequence onto some other commit, and then moves the branch label.

What you can specify, with all the not-terribly-well-documented options, is the branch name—the default is your current branch—and, usually somewhat indirectly, the point at which to *stop* copying.  The "target" commit, which rebase calls `--onto <newbase>`, defaults to the argument you give (if any) for what rebase calls `<upstream>`.

The way this works relies on understanding something else fairly important, which affects the two-dot notation.

Let's go back to the original graph again, before we do any cherry-picking and branch-label-moving, i.e., to what we have before the rebase:

```
... - o - A - B    <-- master
        \
          C - D - E   <-- my-feature
```

Now let's ask git what revisions are in `master..my-feature`:

```
$ git rev-list master..my-feature
e59f6c2d348d465e3147b11098126d3965686098
8413a79e67177d026d2d8e1ac66451b80bb25d62
1f9e0a53489aaca7859722e037a47e93858cbc42
```

(I made these up, but in fact with this setup you would really get just three SHA-1s).

I think a good way to explain this is in terms of color-filling / highlighting (which of course I can't do in this text here, so you must imagine it instead).

Imagine that you start with the tip of `my-feature`, i.e., commit `E`.  Paint this commit green: it's "to be used".  Then, follow its parent pointer back to commit `D`.  Paint this commit green as well.  Follow that to `C` and paint that green; follow that to `o` and paint that one green too, and continue to `o`'s parent(s) all the way through the entire graph.

Then, start with the tip of `master`, i.e., commit `B`.  Paint this commit red: "stop".  Then, follow its parent to commit `A`, and paint this one red.  Follow that to `o`, and paint over the green paint with red paint: "stop".  Follow `o`'s parent(s) all the way, overwriting all their green paint with red paint.

(If you prefer, you can do red first, then green, as long as you *don't* overwrite any red with green.)

The result—the commits that `git rev-list` should list—is exactly those commits that are (still) green, which is just the three we want to rebase.  This is true even though we started the "red list" from commit `B`, the tip of `master`.

The short version of all of this is that, for the purpose of rebasing, what we want—at least for now—is for `git rebase` to treat `master` as the "upstream".  The "upstream" argument for rebase supplies both the "red paint" argument, the left half of the `master..my-feature` revision-specifier, *and* the `--onto` argument: we want to copy commits so that they come after the tip-most commit of `master`.

In fact, you can use `git branch --set-upstream-to` to set `master` (in your own private repository) as the "upstream" of `my-feature`.  An upstream does not have to be a remote-tracking branch like `origin/branch`.  Your own local branches will work fine here.  (But remember that if you do start sharing this branch—by pushing it to a remote git repository like `origin`—you might want, at that point, to start using the remote-tracking branch as the "upstream" from then on, to remind yourself that you're sharing, and get a more typical rebase flow going.  You can change the "upstream" at any point by doing a new `git branch --set-upstream-to`.)

---

<sup>1</sup>The word "branch" is another example of an issue with the git documentation.  It has at least two different meanings.  In the graph that's part of the paragraph to which this is a footnote, `master` is a "branch" (I like to call it a "branch label" or "branch name").  Similarly, `my-feature` is a branch.  Both of these simply label one particular commit—`B` and `E` respectively, in this case.  Each commit, however, has its own pointers to its parent commit(s): `B` points back to `A`, `E` points back to `D`, and so on.  The chain of commits produced by following these parent-pointing arrows is also a "branch".

The exact point at which to stop calling such a chain a "branch" depends on your point of view: `my-feature` might stop at commit `o`, while `master` might continue back through `o`.  Git doesn't really help much here, although there's no always-right answer anyway: it really does depend on what you want to include.

<sup>2</sup>There's a slightly easier way to do this, because `git cherry-pick` can take more than one commit as an argument:

```
$ git cherry-pick <id> <id> <id>
```

for example, or:

```
$ git cherry-pick my-feature~3..my-feature
```

which uses the specifiers described in [the gitrevisions documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html) to get git to find the three IDs.

Answer (score 1):

The thing is, rebase without arguments by default proposes to rebase from the last commit pushed. We can however nudge it in the right direction :

```
git rebase -i <hash>
```

Choose the `<hash>` of the commit *just prior* to the one you want to see in the history. Those hashes can be obtained via `git log`.

Comment: An expression like `HEAD~1` (commit before last commit) should also work. If there are plenty commits, it will be probably easier to copy and paste the hash from log however instead of counting how many commits you wanna rebase.